# What is the URI for clipping a youtube video between start and finish point?

Tags: youtube

Simple query. I want to clip two seconds out of video in YouTube?

Tried what I thought was the start and finish parameters.

https://youtu.be/ZWijx_AgPiA?start=37&end=39

But it keeps playing. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use this approach:

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/Xvjjpzyiig4?start=37&end=39&autoplay=1

Keep in mind, though, the video must be available through embed.

With your video_id `ZWijx_AgPiA` I got - video not available, but, this might be due to region restrictions - or the video is not set to be embed.