# YouTube URI basics: how to cut a clip short

Tags: youtube

Say I've got a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isMFxOLbiro

I know that I can add `&t=5s` say to the end of the URL to start the clip at 5 seconds.

What do I additionally add to the end of the URL to say only play from my predefined start point for just two seconds? I vaguely remember &end=2s but that doesn't work.

Thank you. I know this is relatively trivial.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76198616).